# sign of time partial derivative at a global max

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I've encountered this concept in my PDE class but I believe my issue relates to some fundamental misunderstanding of multivariable calculus that I probably should have understood years ago.

Suppose I have a smooth function $u = u(x,t)$ defined in $\overline{\Omega}\times(0, T]$ where $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain. (I may need additional assumptions here but I am not sure.) Suppose that $u$ obtains its global maximum at $(x_0, t_0) \in \Omega \times (0,T]$. I understand that $|\nabla u(x_0, t_0)| = 0$ and that $\Delta u(x_0, t_0) \leq 0$. But, why is $u_t(x_0, t_0) \geq 0$? I feel like it should be zero for the same reasoning that $u_{x_i x_i}(x_0, t_0) = 0$. Is the problem that $t_0$ could equal $T$? If the time interval was an unbounded set, would anything change?

If anyone can point me to a picture that explains this or some reference that would be very helpful. If this is somehow specific to PDEs, I can provide an example problem where this type of logic is employed.

Comment: As you point out correctly the reason is that $t_0$ could be equal to $T$. Just think about a usual function $f\in C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$. If this function has a maximum at the right endpoint, then you cannot say that the derivative is zero. The only thing you can say is that the derivative has to be positive! If you had an unbounded time interval of the form $(0,\infty)$ then this cannot occurr and you could conclude that $u_t(x_0,t_0)=0$

Comment: @Jake28 Thank you so much! I spent a long time thinking about it and wanted to make sure!!